# How do I write this equation backwards (with inverted matrices)?

Tags: matrices, projection-matrices

My question is what matrix operations are used to get to from eq.(1) to eq.(3)?

I'm pretty clear with eq.(1), solving for the unknown image pts [u,v].

Now I want to solve for an unknown XYZ world point with known image [u,v]. This will require moving matrices from the right to the left side, eq.(3). How do I move matrices K, [R|T] to the left to isolate $W_{xyz}$ like eq.(3)?

eq.(1) $s\cdot\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
  u \\
  v \\
  1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
}_\text{Cam pts} 
= \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}fx & 0 & cx\\0 & fy & cy\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}}_\text{K} 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & t_x\\r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} & t_y\\r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} & t_x\end{bmatrix}}_\text{RT(rotation/translation)} 
 \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
  X \\
  Y \\
  Z \\
  1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
}_\text{World Coordinates} 
$

This simplifies to:

eq.(2) $s\cdot C_{uv}$ = $K\cdot[R|t]\cdot W_{xyz}$

eq.(3)$\underbrace{    \Biggl(
s
\begin{bmatrix}
  u \\
  v \\
  1 \\
\end{bmatrix} K^{-1}-t\Biggr) R^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
  X \\
  Y \\
  Z \\
  1 \\
\end{bmatrix} }_\text{Matrices moved leftwise to solve for World Points X,Y,Z} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrices do not commute, you need to multiply them on the left hand side:
$sR^{-1}\left ( K^{-1}C-t\right )=W_{xyz}$

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please expand by a few steps in between moving the matrices from right-of-equal sign to the left side?

Comment: take a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: User619894's answer is as good as any right answer. I am left though wondering. in general, why in moving away from what we are trying to solve we take the inverse of the matrix. I understand subtracting, adding or multiplying on sides of an equation; but its not intuitive to me why the inverse of a matrix is the answer to moving from one side of the equation to the other..